# How to select current page's rows only in ngx data table in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-data table and using checkbox type of ngx-data table. I want to select current pages rows only but it when i select-all option so it selects all rows in array. My code is here

```
<ngx-datatable-column [width]="50" [sortable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false">
                          <ng-template class="datatable-checkbox" ngx-datatable-header-template let-value="value" let-allRowsSelected="allRowsSelected"
                            let-selectFn="selectFn">
                            <div class="checkbox-fade fade-in-default datatable-header-cell-label">
                              <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="allRowsSelected" (change)="selectFn(!allRowsSelected)" />
                                <span class="cr">
                                  <i class="cr-icon icofont icofont-ui-check txt-primary"></i>
                                </span>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </ng-template>
                          <ng-template class="datatable-checkbox" ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value" let-isSelected="isSelected" let-onCheckboxChangeFn="onCheckboxChangeFn">
                            <div class="checkbox-fade fade-in-default datatable-header-cell-label">
                              <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected" (change)="onCheckboxChangeFn($event)" />
                                <span class="cr">
                                  <i class="cr-icon icofont icofont-ui-check txt-primary"></i>
                                </span>
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </ng-template>
                        </ngx-datatable-column>
```

How can i select only current page rows only on select-all option?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use:

```
[selectAllRowsOnPage] true|false
```

In ngx docs, it says:

> Property to which you can use for determining select all rows on
> current page or not.

example :

```
<ngx-datatable [selectAllRowsOnPage]="true"></ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: Not working for me. It keeps selecting all in my array... not on the current page

Comment: Did anyone gets the solution?

Comment: Is your select do selection on object, if so, it may be because all your object have something similar. I have fix my database test data with more distinction and everything works fine now.

Comment: Did anyone got solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `[selectAllRowsOnPage]` option was broken, a fix was made in version 16.1.0

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/docs/changelog.md